# Volume of solid lies under $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-analysis

Find the volume of solid lies under $z=x^2+y^2$ above $x$-$y$ plane and inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$. I know, for volume we have to us $V=\iiint { \mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz}$ but i was not able to proceed further.

Any hint would be sufficient !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  & V=\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{-\sqrt{2x-{{x}^{2}}}}^{\sqrt{2x-{{x}^{2}}}}{\int_{0}^{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}{dzdydx=}}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{2\cos \theta }{\int_{0}^{{{r}^{2}}}{r\,dzdrd\theta}}} \\ 
 & V=\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{2\cos \theta }{{{r}^{3}}}}drd\theta =4\int_{0}^{2\pi }{{{\cos }^{4}}}\theta d\theta =16\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\cos }^{4}}}\theta d\theta  \\ 
\end{align}
$$V=16\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{5}{2} \right)\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}{2\Gamma \left( 3 \right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was making mistake in limits of z.

Comment: Please. $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\sin }^{2\alpha -1}}}x\,\,{{\cos }^{2\beta -1}}x\,dx=\,\frac{\Gamma (\alpha)\Gamma (\beta)}{2\Gamma \left( \alpha+\beta\right)}$$

Comment: I don't know this identity but this integral can be calculated using walli's fromulae.

Comment: yes we can use it :)